# Android notification with setLights() only (led only) doesn't work

Tags: android

In the past few days I've tried many combinations trying to get the led notification light to work and it only works when notifications use sound. No Sound -> No Led lights. Anyone had a similar issue? I'm testing this on Nexus5x and nexus10, both are behaving the same way. Note: notifications are coming through and show in status bar, but without the led.

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_dog_avatar)
                .setContentText(messageText)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)

// when this is enabled, I see the led lights flashing, but the sound 
// is there also
//                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)

//with this or without, same effect
//                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setLights(65280, 500, 500)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get this? I'm trying on my Pixel, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No, still don't know how this can be done, ended up making them totally silent.